# Completion handler as var in Swift from Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift

I must present this completion handler in Swift as variable:

```
-test:(void(^)(id result, NSError* error))completion;
```

What must this look like in Swift? Is in this case id == AnyObject and NSError == Error?

Comment: If you already have that method in ObjectiveC, you can see how it appear in Swift with the Xcode "Generated Interface".

Comment: thanks it's a little bit help me, but now xCode want to correct this competition handler when I create a variable, in Swift it's look like: 
(completionBlock completion: (@escaping (Any?, Error?) -> Swift.Void)!)

Comment: What's a "competition handler"?

Comment: sorry I was wrong write it's - completion handler

Answer (score 0):

`id` is imported into Swift as `Any`, `NSError *` becomes `Error?` in Swift 3 so your completion handler should read like this in Swift:

```
func completionHandler(result: Any, error: Error?) {
    // Do something
}

obj.test(completionHandler)
```

Or if you want to define it inline:

```
let handler = { (result: Any, error: Error?) -> Void in
    // Do something
}
obj.test(handler)
```